NIO Event Loops and Swift async/await
I'm using swift-grpc which uses swift-nio under the hood. I'm having a hard time reconciling my understanding of Event Loops in the context of async/await. Using the following code as a reference:
class GRPCClientStub {
    static let authClient = Auth_AuthServiceAsyncClient(
        channel: GRPCClientStub.shared.channel
    )
    static let userClient = User_UserServiceAsyncClient(
        channel: GRPCClientStub.shared.channel
    )

    
    private static let shared = try! GRPCClientStub()
    private let group: EventLoopGroup = PlatformSupport.makeEventLoopGroup(loopCount: 1)
    private let channel: GRPCChannel

    private init() throws {
        channel = try GRPCChannelPool.with(
            target: .host("localhost", port: 8000),
            transportSecurity: .plaintext,
            eventLoopGroup: group
        )
    }
    
    deinit {
        try? group.syncShutdownGracefully()
    }
}

My questions are the following:

Is an event loop group like PlatformSupport.makeEventLoopGroup(loopCount: 1) creating a separate executor different from the executor created by Swift's native runtime?
Is an event loop the same thing as a thread? i.e. it there a one-to-one mapping between event loops and threads?
Should one increase the loop count and use a single gRPC channel for multiple clients or should one create a separate gRPC channel for each client? What would be the difference?
Should one annotate the event loop / clients with a global actor? If not, do the loops contend with the MainActor?

I understand that I'm asking multiple questions under the same post but IMO these questions are really symptoms of the same underlying issue which is that I don't understand event loops in the context of Swift's async/await and there's no sources that bridges this gap.

The short answer is that there is no direct relation between event loops and Swift async/await. Event loops are something that Google has come up wit as an abstraction on top of the various platforms. You would need to dig into that code to see what they have done
